# A Find/Replace in VBA with multiple match cases

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I have to remove spacebars near some special charatcers like `+`,`=`,`:`, etc. Currently I have lots of copy-pasted codeblocks e.g.

```
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .Text = " ="
    .Replacement.Text = "="
    .Forward = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .Text = "= "
    .Replacement.Text = "="
    .Forward = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

How can I enumerate a series of match cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a more simplified code for your troubles. If you need to add more special characters then simply append it to the array !

```
Dim tmpArr, iCtr As Integer

tmpArr = Array("+", "=", ":")

For iCtr = 0 To UBound(tmpArr)
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .Text = " " & tmpArr(iCtr) & " "
        .Replacement.Text = tmpArr(iCtr)
        .Forward = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next
```

Hope this helps ! Good luck !